# Changing option value with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

```
<select id="dd">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

//change option to 2; works
$("#dd").find('option[value=2]').attr("selected",true);
$("#dd").find('option[value=2]').attr("selected",false)

//change option to 3; works
$("#dd").find('option[value=3]').attr("selected",true);
$("#dd").find('option[value=3]').attr("selected",false);

//change option back to 2; doesn't work
$("#dd").find('option[value=2]').attr("selected",true);
```

Changing value to back a value that was set earlier, doesn't work.. 
Any idea? if I am doing something wrong...

Comment: Neither of your examples work, why would you say they do?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I was trying to change the selection in a drop down list identified by dd using java script. The problem, changing the selection doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying for?

```js
$('#set2').click(function(){
  $("#dd option[value=2]").prop("selected",true);
});

$('#set3').click(function(){
  $("#dd option[value=3]").prop("selected",true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dd">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<button id="set2">Set to 2</button>
<button id="set3">Set to 3</button>
```

Comment: yes... .prop("selected",true) works well instead for .attr("selected",true);